# Seems like webpack ignores 'include' and 'exclude' rules

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader, sass-loader

I have following folder setup:

```
app/
  scss/
    lib/
      grid.css
    main.scss
webpack/
  webpack.config.js
```

in my **webpack.config.js** I have following loaders to handle scss and css:

```
  {
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    exclude: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app/scss/lib/'),
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
      'style-loader', 'css-loader?module!resolve-url!postcss-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap'
    )
  },
  {
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    include: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app/scss/lib/'),
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
  }
```

idea here is that css-loader uses modules essentially rewriting a class name like `.red` to something random like `.JHSKJasdasa` however, I want it to exclude **/lib** folder and leave classes that are in it same as they are (vanilla), however still, classes inside **grid.css** like `.container` become randomized.

Comment: You are `excluding` and again `including` the `/lib` folder.  The configuration above is clearly wrong. You don't have to exclude anything.  Only include the stuff which you want to be `webpacked`.

Comment: @Venky I am including it back again but with different loaders. How would you recommend restructuring?

Comment: I would use something like `dist/assets/......` folder to store the files which are to be `webpacked` and `distributed`. All other non-distributable files in a different folder `src/assets.....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely answer is that webpack is getting confused by the `path.join` - [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders) specifies `path.resolve`. I think it might do a straight string comparison of the paths, so the relative `..` is breaking it, therefore the exclusion/inclusion isn't working correctly. `path.resolve` should resolve to the absolute path.

If that doesn't work, try adding a folder `app/scss/src` (or similar) to separate out the code you want to use css-loader on. Then `include` that rather than `exclude`ing `lib`.